# Should there be a better term than duplicate when closing a question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, close-reasons

I'm a programmer, so I love precision in language, to avoid things like ambiguity in specs. So I *really* hate the term "duplicate" as used within Stack Overflow. Dictionary definitions have that word meaning (for example):

> 1. a copy exactly like an original.
> 2. anything corresponding in all respects to something else.

"All respects" and "exactly like an original" means that "exact duplicate" is a redundant phrase. I'll happily agree that a copy-pasted question or one that is a rephrasing of another could be called a duplicate. But if someone's question is only similar in *some* respects to another, it is not accurately called a duplicate.

I don't say this just to be a language lawyer. I'm saying this as a user that does some casual moderating tasks. If someone flags their question as "not really a duplicate," and it's not, I want to re-open it! If however, the reason for closing is more precise, like:

> This question is so similar to another question, that it will be closed. This is so that all relevant answers for the same problem will be kept in one place. If you believe there is something different enough in your question to warrant a separate set of answers, please edit your question to highlight the differences so your question can be considered for re-opening.

...then this could lead to less unnecessary moderator flags and better, more distinctive questions.

Should we use something other than "duplicate" to describe similar questions?

Comment: There are questions out there that are *simply* duplicated.  They may be worded in different, exotic ways, but the core essence of the question is the same.  I'm not so sure that this wording makes sense.

Comment: Yes but that's just being pedantic.  A question is not a programming construct, so you do not apply programming rules to it.  It is instead a language construct, and its quite clear under language rules that a question that is stated differently but effectively has the same meaning is a duplicate.

Comment: @JK. exactly dictionary definition #2 then as posted in the question. Self-answering questions are the best.

Comment: @JK., I'm apparently talking about something different than you. For example, question A says "This output from this PHP code has an extra gap at the top of the page," and question B says "in this HTML email generated from a Razor template, there are extra blank lines." In both cases, the answer may lie in understanding HTML whitespace rules, but the questions are not duplicates at all.

Comment: ... nor is it likely they should be closed as duplicates.

Comment: My rant is probably misplaced, then. I think what I'm mostly seeing is poorly closed questions. If the community agrees that things that are only somewhat connected aren't duplicates, then the term is probably sufficient.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The term "duplicate" is perfect; it shouldn't be changed.

> But if someone's question is only similar in some respects to another, it is not accurately called a duplicate.

Our definition of "duplicate" is: when the correct answer to question A is also the correct answer to question B, then B is a duplicate of A.

This definition works well and intuitively in the vast majority of cases. Occasionally a user will argue that "How to do 1+2" is different from "How to do 2+3", usually to get their duplicate question reopened, but this is exceedingly rare, and not worth catering to.

From my experience, our definition of "duplicate" works well, even for new users. Changing it to "similar" would probably create *more* confusion and blur the boundaries of when this close reason should be applied - and when it shouldn't.

Comment: By this logic, since the answer to both `5 + 7` and `6 * 2` are 12, those expressions are duplicates. Gotcha.

Comment: @Jacob Addition is a different method than multiplication.

Comment: Right, just being pedantic again since you said "when the correct answer to question A is also the correct answer to question B, then B is a duplicate of A." They would actually need to correspond in all respects, including the operators used. My point is in defense of reopening overly-aggressive application of "duplicate" close votes, but from your other comment, I think we're on the same page that those are invalid.

Comment: @Jacob Except SO does not provide values as a solution, it provides the *way* to solve things. So, going by your example, the question `5+7` and the question `5+10` would be duplicates - as the question is, essentially, "How does the addition operator work in mathematics?" `6*2` is not a duplicate, as it's the question "How does the *multiplication* operator work in mathematics?"